# Поиск всех .exe файлов в системе

Tags: python, python-3.x, ос

Стоит задача написать скрипт, который будет проходить по файловой системе и записывать в список название файла с расширением .exe.

```
import os    
lst = []
    items = os.walk(f"C:/")
    for i in items:
        for k in i:
            if type(k) == str:
                if k.split(".")[-1] == "EXE" or k.split(".")[-1] == "exe":
                    app_window.current_item_label.setText(f"Файл: {k}")
                    lst.append(k)
            elif type(k) == list:
                for j in k:
                    if j.split(".")[-1] == "EXE" or j.split(".")[-1] == "exe":
                        app_window.current_item_label.setText(f"Файл: {j}")
                        lst.append(j)
```

Для достижения желаемого была использована библиотека "os" и функция "walk". На выходе я получаю список с 6184 названиями файлов, но было замечено, что функция проходит не по всей файловой системе, первоначально она обнаруживает перечень папок, приведенный ниже.

```
('C:/', ['$Recycle.Bin', '$WinREAgent', 'Config.Msi', 'Documents and Settings', 'Drivers', 'MSOCache', 'PerfLogs', 'Program Files', 'Program Files (x86)', 'ProgramData', 'Recovery', 'System Volume Information', 'Users', 'WCH.CN', 'Windows'], ['DumpStack.log.tmp', 'hiberfil.sys', 'pagefile.sys', 'swapfile.sys'])
```

Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу вытащить названия файлов из папок Users, Program Files, Program Files (x86), до них функция попросту не доходит.

Comment: А с админскими правами пробовали запускать? Может прав у скрипта нет в эти папки заходить.

Comment: Оффтоп. Я бы переписал код на `pathlib`, пример: `from pathlib import Path` + `for file in Path("C:/").rglob("*.exe"): print(file)`. Да и с `os.walk` можно немного проще сделать - он всегда возвращает кортеж из 3 элементов и их можно прямо в `for` разложить на переменные (см. в пример https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk): `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(f"C:/"):`

Comment: Пробовал админские права, на результат не повлияло. Возможно причиной проблемы служит то, что название папок переведено на русский, то есть они называются "Файлы программ" и тд. При этом если прописывать в пути "C:\Program Files", то все равно переход осуществляется в нужную директорию без каких-либо проблем. Попробую переписать на pathlib, возможно тогда будет результат

Comment: C `pathlib` действительно проще и удобнее. Теперь скрипт находит все файлы в рамках тест-кейсов. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно рекурсивно проходить по всем внутренним каталогам и искать фалы таким образом:

```
import os
import glob

directory = "С:\\"

files = []
for root, dirs, file in os.walk(directory):
    for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(root, "*.exe")):
        files.append(f)

for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Имейте в виду, что скрипт должен быть запущен от имени администратора, чтобы получить доступ ко всем каталогам и файлам